# Python - invalid syntax for short for loop

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble with a for loop. I get SyntaxEror: invalid syntax line 7 when I try to run the code below:

```
lst = list()
x= int(input("enter numbers,0 to stop"))
while(x!=0):
    lst.append(x)

newlst = list()
newlst.append(i) for i in lst if i not in newlst
print(newlst[1:-1])
```

its giving me:

```
newlst.append(i) for i in lst if i not in newlst
                 ^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can only use this type of syntax in a list comprehension (with `[ .. ]`) or a generator expression (with `( ... )`). See: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions In principle, you could use a list comprehension here, but generally it is considered bad style (because you wouldn't use the output, you'd just be doing it for side effects). So better style is to write a conventional for-loop.

Comment: The while loop is incorrect as well.  The input should be in the while loop; otherwise, after entering a non-zero number, the list will be filled until a memory error with that one number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No way to iterate like this

```
newlst.append(i) for i in lst if i not in newlst
```

You can do it by regular loop:

```
for i in lst:
    if i not in newlst:
        newlst.append(i)
```

or by a list comprehension

```
[newlst.append(i) for i in lst if i not in newlst]
```

In this case the regular loop is recommended because a list comprehension builds a useless list of None values and throws it away.

Comment: Don't  use a list comprehension for a side effect.  Use a regular loop.  In this case it builds a useless list of `None` values and throws it away.